# Java - Boolean state not changing

Tags: java, boolean, state

I've got this code here:

```
if ( event.getSource() == Square0 ) 
        {

            if ( PlayerOneTurn == true ) Square0.setBackground(Color.red);
            if ( PlayerOneTurn == true ) PlayerOneTurn = false ;

            if ( PlayerOneTurn == false ) Square0.setBackground(Color.blue) ;

        }
```

If it's not clear, I want the background to turn red and the state of PlayerOneTurn to change to false, so then it changes blue when I click it again.
It works but `if ( PlayerOneTurn == true ) PlayerOneTurn = false ;` doesn't seem to change the value of the variable.
Am I using completely the wrong statement or missing something out?

Comment: You don't need to compare boolean values with true or false. Just write `if(boolField)` for checking if it is true and `if(!boolField)` to check if it is false.

Comment: A side comment: Variables by convention begin with lower case letters.  E.g. playerOneTurn.

Answer (score 1):

Use `else if` and similar constructs.

You **overwrite** the value of `PlayerOneTurn` in line 3.

Also make sure you trigger a repaint when you change visuals.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing color to red and with first `if` and changing it back to blue with third `if` statement, Modify your code by changing `if` to `if-else` like this

```
if ( PlayerOneTurn == true ) 
{
     Square0.setBackground(Color.red);
     PlayerOneTurn = false;
}
else
{
     Square0.setBackground(Color.blue) ;
     PlayerOneTurn = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an else if

```
if (PlayerOneTurn) {
 Square0.setBackground(Color.red);
PlayerOneTurn = false;
}
else
{
 Square0.setBackground(Color.blue) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is setting the color to red, then setting `PlayerOneTurn` to false, then setting the color to blue again, because, well, `PlayerOneTurn` is now false.

What you want is

```
if ( event.getSource() == Square0 ) {

        if ( PlayerOneTurn == true ) {
            Square0.setBackground(Color.red);
            PlayerOneTurn = false ;
        } else {
            Square0.setBackground(Color.blue) ;
            PlayerOneTurn = true;
        }
    }
```

Or, more idiomatic regarding booleans :

```
if ( event.getSource() == Square0 ) {

        if ( PlayerOneTurn ) {
            Square0.setBackground(Color.red);
        } else {
            Square0.setBackground(Color.blue) ;
        }

        PlayerOneTurn = !PlayerOneTurn;  // True becomes false and false becomes true
    }
```